# I want to create Handler that will be catch all Logs of web aplications on Tomcat, and

Tags: tomcat, logging, handler, java.util.logging

I want to create Handler that will be catch all Logs of web  aplications on Tomcat,
I Created my Handler class, compiled it and put on `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` , and `common.loader` has this directory. After this I modified the `logging.properties` file and added the handler:

`handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, logshowaplication.ErrorsListHandler`
I put some filestream, and when object Handler created, it will write some message in file.
and there aren't mistakes when I run tomcat, but when I run it, this message isn't appear in file, therefore Handler object not creates. I'm new in Java and ask you for help. sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle your new handler into a jar file.  Then [modify the class path in the startup script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590330/custom-java-util-logging-handler-in-tomcat) to include your new handler jar.  Finally, you have to modify both the `handlers` and the `.handlers` lines in the logging.properties to include your new handler.