# How can I catch tomcat logs by using java.util.logging?

Tags: tomcat, logging, java.util.logging

How can I catch tomcat logs by using java.util.logging?
I haven't got idea how to bind logs to my handler

Comment: catch tomcat logs? catch them in your application? please expand your question so it can be answered.

Comment: I wanted to add my custom handler and add tomcat logger to it.

Comment: but now I created a libraary. it adds in project and call method install with parameter "name of app". it Adds root logger to my handler in this library and after it it sends logs on server.

Comment: Related: [Custom java.util.logging Handler in tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590330/custom-java-util-logging-handler-in-tomcat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to create Handler that will be catch all Logs of web aplications on Tomcat, and](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960561/i-want-to-create-handler-that-will-be-catch-all-logs-of-web-aplications-on-tomca)