# Override apache tomcat log file rotation

Tags: tomcat, logging, catalina.out

In `tomcat/logs` directory we have different set of files which are normally rotated everyday. Is there any procedure to override rotating mechanism for `catalina.out`, `localhost_access_log`, `manager.${DATE}.log`, `host-manager.${DATE}.log` 
I don't want to rely on **logrotate** utility as there is a chance of losing data in log files.
After reading couple of articles there is one way to create a new file by adding some configurational changes in `tomcat/conf/server.xml` file

```
<Valve
className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
directory="logs"
prefix="catalina."
suffix=".out"
pattern='%a %A %b %B %h %l %m %p %q %u %t "%r" %s %U %D %S'
resolveHosts="false"
rotatable="true"/>
```

this piece of configuration does not fulfill my requirement. `tomcat/conf/log4.properties` changes do not work for me.

your support is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can extend the `org.apache.juli.FileHandler` and override the `publish` where the log file is rotated on first wirte after midnight. Then [configure your custom FileHandler as tomcat default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590330/custom-java-util-logging-handler-in-tomcat#20384327)

Comment: @Selaron what if i define new handler in log4j.properties and change all the catalina logging properties. will it work?